# No puedo usar una dirección desde la calculadora de subred

Tags: aws, redes, ip

Hola estoy haciendo un curso en AWS donde tengo que agregar una subnet, anteriormente ya coloqué una y fue un éxito pero ésta segunda no puedo crearla. Estos son los datos que estoy usando la dirección:

IPv4 CIDRs:
**172.31.0.0/16**

y quiero agregar en el form IPv4 CIDR blockInfo la siguiente:
**172.31.0.1/16**

Me manda el siguiente error:
CIDR Address overlaps with existing Subnet CIDR: **172.31.0.0/16.**

pero en la calculadora indica que puedo usar esa dirección, ya que me arroja éste rango:
**172.31.0.1 - 172.31.255.254**

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal por qué no puedo usar **172.31.0.1/16**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las redes se identifican por una dirección y una máscara de red.

Con estos dos valores sa calcula la dirección de red. Ésta se haya realizando una operación AND binaria entre ambos valores.

Así, para la red 172.31.0.0/16, tenemos

```
   172       31      0         0
10101100 00011111 00000000 00000000

  /16 -> primeros 16 bits a 1
11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000
```

Con lo que la dirección de red será

```
  10101100 00011111 00000000 00000000
& 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000
--------------------------------------
  10101100 00011111 00000000 00000000
```

Ahora, para saber si una IP pertenece o no a una red bastará con realizar la operación AND a la IP. Si el valor resultante coincide con la dirección de red entonces estamos en la misma red.

En este punto tu has intentado dar de alta una red nueva 172.31.0.1/16. Si calculamos la dirección de red:

```
  10101100 00011111 00000000 00000001
& 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000
--------------------------------------
  10101100 00011111 00000000 00000000
```

Vemos que el resultado obtenido es el mismo al de la primera red. Esto quiere decir que ambas redes son, en esencia, indistinguibles la una de la otra. Si el sistema te dejase dar de alta ambas redes entonces no sería capaz de saber si una IP pertenece a una red o a la otra.

Para que sean dos redes realmente diferentes tienes que cambiar alguno de los bits para los cuales la máscara tiene valor 1. Por ejemplo 172.63.0.0/16

```
  10101100 00111111 00000000 00000000
& 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000
--------------------------------------
  10101100 00111111 00000000 00000000
             ^ este bit ha cambiado
```

Comment: muchas gracias, funcionó!!!